# Django: How to pass a python list from view to Jquery?

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a python list (fileContents) fetched from a file in my views.py:

**views.py:**

```
def job_progress_logs(request):
    fileContents = [line.strip() for line in open('C:\VSA Automation.log')]
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"fileData" : fileContents}), mimetype="application/javascript; charset=UTF-8")
```

I want to display this list on my template.py by JQuery:

**template.py:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showData(){
var url = "/vsawebauto/automation/results/job_progress_logs";
    $.getJSON(url, function (data){
    // show the data
    var txtData="";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       txtData += data.fileData;
      }
      $('#progress').text(txtData);
  });
}
</script> 


<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(showData, 3 * 1000);
</script>
<div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
</body>
```

But I am not able to do it with the above code. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: try `JSON.parse(data.responseText).length` and `txtData += JSON.parse(data.responseText).fileData`

Answer (score 0):

Encase your code inside `DOM Ready` Handler

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       setInterval(showData, 3 * 1000);
   });
</script>
```

It is better idea to move the script to just before the body so that the `HTML` rendering is not blocked due to script

Answer (score 0):

Please use
`var parsedata = JSON.parse(data);`   
In your AJAX function.you must parse data.